# Al cambiar de ruta en angular debo recargar la página para que firebase me actualice los datos

Tags: angular, firebase

Estoy usando este servicio para obtener datos desde firebase, pero al cambiar de ruta en angular 7 debo recargar la página para que los datos aparezcan saben que problema tengo ?

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items');
this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  }))
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que si lo tienes en el componente y cuando se ejecuta el OnDestroy elimina todo, prueba usando un servicio y que tome en el constructor del componente la data del servicio

Comment: te recomiendo de tu respuesta quitar la pregunta, pues este espacio es solo para dar respuestas y no para pedir aclaraciones al OP

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo directamente desde un servicio y desde el .ts del componente lo estoy consumiendo